# Как вызвать метод, до вызова другого метода в angular2?

Tags: angular2

Недавно начал изучать angular. У меня есть форма обратной связи, на этой форме капча. При нажатии на кпопку вызываются следующие методы:

```
(click)="sendMessage(); sendForm.reset()"
```

А мне нужно что, до того как отправилось сообщение, вызвать метод проверки капчи, и в зависимости от результата, выполнить отправку. Какие есть для этого способы?

Answer (score 0):

Самый очевидный, это написать ещё один метод, реализующий нужную логику и пользоваться им